# Remove element by id

Tags: javascript, dom

When removing an element with standard JavaScript, you must go to its parent first:

```
var element = document.getElementById("element-id");
element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
```

Having to go to the parent node first seems a bit odd to me, is there a reason JavaScript works like this?

Comment: As James said, the DOM does not support removing an object directly. You have to go to its parent and remove it from there. Javascript won't let an element commit suicide, but it does permit infanticide...

Comment: Is there a reason? [Richard Feynman says no](http://lesswrong.com/r/discussion/lw/99c/transcript_richard_feynman_on_why_questions/). (Well the technical justification is easy to see if you have written any tree-structure programs. The child must inform the parent _anyway_ otherwise the tree structure may be broken. Since it must do it internally anyway, if it provided you a one line function, it's just a convenient function for you that you may as well define yourself.)

Comment: The only reason i see is that there should be always a root element in an xml/xhtml document, so you won't be able to remove it because it doesn't have a parent

Comment: I quite like [Johan's workaround](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18120786), and I'm not sure why those functions aren't provided natively. As evidenced by the number of viewers, it's a very common operation.

Comment: @kizzx2 Did you mean your link to go to "Feynman: F*****' magnets, how do they work?" Because, um, that's where it points, and I don't see anything in that transcript about DOM and element removal. (Okay, okay, I got what you meant, but magnetism is much less a human construct than JavaScript, I believe, making the OP's question here much more viable than that interviewer's. ;^D That said, admittedly, IANAP[hysicist].)

Comment: @ruffin Well you kinda have the read the whole thing to get the point. But basically it's responding to the "seems a bit odd" part. Any "reason" would _also_ "seems a bit odd". Sometimes the world is just the way it is. And the actual "technical reason" is the tree-structure stuff but I reckon it wouldn't have been an intuitive answer as well so put that in parenthesis in a comment)

Comment: IMHO: The reason for this is the same as I've seen in other environments: You are performing an action based on your "link" to something. You can't delete it while you're linked to it. Like cutting a tree limb. Sit on the side closest to the tree while cutting or the result will be ... unfortunate (although funny).

Comment: You can use `element.remove()` directly as of ES5. You don't need the parent!

Comment: @MarkHenderson it's [prolicide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolicide), not infanticide, and as an _aside_, Javascript does allow [parricide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parricide) via the grandparents. 

Answer (score 138, accepted):

#### Update 2011

This was added to the [DOM spec](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-childnode-remove) back [in 2011](https://github.com/whatwg/dom/commit/85ff0b8#diff-d8adac750acc947123f2d8e77244ac97ed1e32fa65c0ca334c08fc620ab7ad60R3756), so you can just use:

```js
element.remove()
```

The DOM is organized in a tree of nodes, where each node has a value, along with a list of references to its child nodes. So `element.parentNode.removeChild(element)` mimics exactly what is happening internally: First you go the parent node, then remove the reference to the child node.

As of DOM4, a helper function is provided to do the same thing: [`element.remove()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/ChildNode.remove). This [works in 96% of browsers](https://caniuse.com/childnode-remove) (as of 2020), but not IE 11.

**If you need to support older browsers, you can**:

- Remove elements via the parent node
- Modify the native DOM functions, as in [Johan Dettmar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18120786/405550), or
- Use a [DOM4 polyfill](https://github.com/WebReflection/dom4#dom4).

Comment: Please don't _"modify the native DOM functions"_.

Answer (score 764):

I know that augmenting native DOM functions isn't always the best or most popular solution, but this works fine for modern browsers.

```
Element.prototype.remove = function() {
    this.parentElement.removeChild(this);
}
NodeList.prototype.remove = HTMLCollection.prototype.remove = function() {
    for(var i = this.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if(this[i] && this[i].parentElement) {
            this[i].parentElement.removeChild(this[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

And then you can remove elements like this

```
document.getElementById("my-element").remove();
```

or

```
document.getElementsByClassName("my-elements").remove();
```

**Note:** this solution doesn't work for IE 7 and below. For more info about extending the DOM read this [article](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/).

**EDIT**: Reviewing my answer in 2019, `node.remove()` has come to the rescue and can be used as follows (without the polyfill above):

```
document.getElementById("my-element").remove();
```

or

```
[...document.getElementsByClassName("my-elements")].map(n => n && n.remove());
```

These functions are available in all modern browsers (not IE). Read more on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove).

Comment: what about `while(this.length){ this[0].parentElement.removeChild(this[0]); }` ?

Comment: @AurelianoFarSuau, that should probably work as well (haven't tested it myself). However this loop will read the length value each time which might be slightly slower. Also to my knowledge you'd need `if(this[i] && this[i].parentElement)` to be sure that the current element still exists and has a parent element, otherwise you might get errors thrown for nested elements, etc.

Comment: Don't do this. Simply remove items the way the language intends. Anyone familiar with parsing XML will recognize the need to get to the parent to delete children. HTML is a superset of XML (sort of).

Comment: Especially useful when using a framework like DHTMLX suite, specifically when you have multiple forms in tabbars with the same name and id and you're trying to implement AJAX. Paste this at the top of each form to nullify previously loaded forms so that the current form is the only one that's loaded. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 332):

Crossbrowser and IE >= 11:

```
document.getElementById("element-id").outerHTML = "";
```

Comment: This seems the simplest, most reliable, and fastest solution.  I don't need to delete the element so I skip the last line, but that shouldn't add any overhead either way.. *Note*:  I found this while trying to find a faster than `$.ready` js alternative to `noscript` tags.  In order to use it how I wanted, I had to wrap it in a 1ms `setTimeout` function.  This solves all of my problems at once.  Gracias.

Comment: Keep in mind `outerHTML` is still a new(er) addition to to the standard. If you're looking for support on any software >6 at the time of writing, you'll need another solution. The `remove` function mentioned by others is a similar case. As usual it's safe to implement a polyfill.

Comment: `delete element` does nothing as you can't delete variables in JS, only keys ;) Check for yourself it doesn't work by `console.log(element)` after `delete element`...

Comment: This is a bit slower than `removeChild` (about 6-7% on my system). See https://jsperf.com/clear-outerhtml-v-removechild/2

Comment: This might leave a space where an iframe used to be if that's what you're trying to remove.

Answer (score 198):

You could make a `remove` function so that you wouldn't have to think about it every time:

```
function removeElement(id) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(id);
    return elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
}
```

Comment: If you want the one-liner without going global, you can change `elem` to `remove.elem`. That way the function references itself, so you don't have to create another global variable. :-)

Comment: so, why do you need to return the elem? Why not `function remove(id) { document.getElementById(id).parentNote.removeChild(document.getElementById(id)); }`

Comment: @ZachL: Whilst your solution might seem the more obvious, it performs two DOM lookups which is slower and something the other solutions seem to want to avoid.

Comment: Does not work. Too many errors. This works :
var elem = document.getElementById('id') ; elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);

Comment: Wow, why so complicated. Just pass the element itself to the function instead of a id string. This way the element is accessible in the whole function plus it stays a one liner

Comment: @DavidFariña whale, if you wanted to remove an element with that approach, then you would maintain a reference to a deleted dom element. I am not quite certain what this would look like in a for loop that has its own scope, but I should think that your approach might lead to memory leaks (as you might be maintaining references to deleted elements, so they would not be garbage collected). I am not 100% certain of this. While your approach is fine as long as you understand that you need not maintain references in a global or large scope or cross-function, it can get messy.

Comment: @dylnmc good point! I didnt think of this. But this can be avoided by simply setting the variable that holds the (not anymore existing) element to null.

Answer (score 99):

[It's what the DOM supports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element#Methods). Search that page for "remove" or "delete" and [removeChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild) is the only one that removes a node.

Comment: That answers my original question, but why does JavaScript work like this?

Comment: I'm just guessing here, But I would assume it has to do with memory management. The parent node most likely holds a list of pointers to the child nodes. If you just deleted a node (without using parent), the parent would still hold the pointer and cause a memory leak. So the api forces you to call a function on the parent to delete the child. this also is nice because it can walk the tree down through the child nodes calling remove on each of them, and not leaking memory.

Comment: hey guys, even though that reference doesn't have this, i found it accidentally. writing `element.remove();` will work. Maybe it's something new. But first time for me and it works. I think it should have worked always as it's very basic must have stuff.

Comment: But it does not work in IE7 and below. 
From IE7 and below, remove() does not work

Comment: If I had to guess, the reason it works like this is that DOM elements can't remove themselves. You're removing the proverbial carpet from under it's feet. You have to remove it from the container. At least that's how I try to think of it.

Answer (score 39):

For removing one element:

```
 var elem = document.getElementById("yourid");
 elem.parentElement.removeChild(elem);
```

For removing all the elements with for example a certain class name:

```
 var list = document.getElementsByClassName("yourclassname");
 for(var i = list.length - 1; 0 <= i; i--)
 if(list[i] && list[i].parentElement)
 list[i].parentElement.removeChild(list[i]);
```

Comment: This is well covered by the existing answers.

Comment: Why is the `if(list[i] && list[i].parentElement)` line necessary? Isn't the existence of each element guaranteed by the fact that it was returned by the `getElementsByClassName` method?

Comment: Unfortunately the existence is not really guaranteed as far as I know, but I do not know the details about it. I just experienced some strange undefined or null value once, and I put that check there without further investigation. So this is a bit of hack.

Comment: It should be `document.getElementsByClassName(...`

Comment: Really, it should be `Elements` instead of `Element`. Thank you.

Answer (score 28):

you can just use `element.remove()`

Comment: Josh, it is valid javascript, except only Firefox and Chrome implemented it (See MDN)

Comment: My bad, [`element.remove()` *is* valid JavaScript with DOM4](http://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#childnode), and works in all modern browsers, naturally with the exception of Internet Explorer.

Comment: According to MDN's [ChildNode.remove()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove) page, Edge supports it as well.

Comment: MDN also provides a polyfill for IE support https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove#Polyfill

Answer (score 21):

You can directly remove that element by using `remove()` method of DOM.

here's an example:

```
let subsWrapper = document.getElementById("element_id");
subsWrapper.remove();
//OR directly.
document.getElementById("element_id").remove();
```

Answer (score 20):

The `ChildNode.remove()` method removes the object from the tree it belongs to.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove

Here is a fiddle that shows how you can call `document.getElementById('my-id').remove()`

https://jsfiddle.net/52kp584L/

**

### There is no need to extend NodeList. It has been implemented already.

**

Comment: Note, this isn't supported in any version of IE!

Answer (score 12):

According to DOM level 4 specs, which is the current version in development, there are some new handy mutation methods available: `append()`, `prepend()`, `before()`, `after()`, `replace()`, and `remove()`.

https://catalin.red/removing-an-element-with-plain-javascript-remove-method/

Answer (score 9):

You can simply use

```
document.getElementById("elementID").outerHTML="";
```

It works in all browsers, even on Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 8):

Functions that use `ele.parentNode.removeChild(ele)` won't work for elements you've created but not yet inserted into the `HTML`.  Libraries like `jQuery` and `Prototype` wisely use a method like the following to evade that limitation.

```
_limbo = document.createElement('div');
function deleteElement(ele){
    _limbo.appendChild(ele);
    _limbo.removeChild(ele);
}
```

I think `JavaScript` works like that because the DOM's original designers held parent/child and previous/next navigation as a higher priority than the `DHTML` modifications that are so popular today. Being able to read from one `<input type='text'>` and write to another by relative location in the DOM was useful in the mid-90s, a time when the dynamic generation of entire `HTML` forms or interactive GUI elements was barely a twinkle in some developer's eye.

Answer (score 8):

> Having to go to the parent node first seems a bit odd to me, is there a reason JavaScript works like this?

The function name is `removeChild()`, and how is it possible to remove the child when there's no parent? :)

On the other hand, you do not always have to call it as you have shown. `element.parentNode` is only a helper to get the parent node of the given node. If you already know the parent node, you can just use it like this:

Ex:

```
// Removing a specified element when knowing its parent node
var d = document.getElementById("top");
var d_nested = document.getElementById("nested");
var throwawayNode = d.removeChild(d_nested);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild

=========================================================

To add something more:

Some answers have pointed out that instead of using `parentNode.removeChild(child);`, you can use `elem.remove();`. But as I have noticed, there is a difference between the two functions, and it's not mentioned in those answers.

If you use `removeChild()`, it will return a reference to the removed node.

```
var removedChild = element.parentNode.removeChild(element); 
console.log(removedChild); //will print the removed child.
```

But if you use `elem.remove();`, it won't return you the reference.

```
var el = document.getElementById('Example');
var removedChild = el.remove(); //undefined
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove

This behavior can be observed in Chrome and FF. I believe It's worth noticing :)

Hope my answer adds some value to the question and will be helpful!!

Answer (score 8):

### Shortest

I improve [Sai Sunder answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22100324/860099) because OP uses ID which allows to avoid getElementById:

```
elementId.remove();
```

```js
box2.remove();          // remove BOX 2

this["box-3"].remove(); // remove BOX 3 (for Id with 'minus' character)
```

```html
<div id="box1">My BOX 1</div>
<div id="box2">My BOX 2</div>
<div id="box-3">My BOX 3</div>
<div id="box4">My BOX 4</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

> Having to go to the parent node first seems a bit odd to me, is there
>   a reason JavaScript works like this?

IMHO: The reason for this is the same as I've seen in other environments: You are performing an action based on your "link" to something. You can't delete it while you're linked to it.

Like cutting a tree limb. Sit on the side closest to the tree while cutting or the result will be ... unfortunate (although funny).

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, removing a node directly does not work in Firefox, only Internet Explorer. So, to support Firefox, you have to go up to the parent to remove it's child.

Ref: http://chiragrdarji.wordpress.com/2007/03/16/removedelete-element-from-page-using-javascript-working-in-firefoxieopera/

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question, and the page you linked to provides a worse solution than mine.

Answer (score 2):

This one actually comes from `Firefox`... for once, `IE` was ahead of the pack and allowed the removal of an element directly.

This is just my assumption, but I believe the reason that you must remove a child through the parent is due to an issue with the way `Firefox` handled the reference.

If you call an object to commit hari-kari directly, then immediately after it dies, you are still holding that reference to it. This has the potential to create several nasty bugs... such as failing to remove it, removing it but keeping references to it that appear valid, or simply a memory leak.

I believe that when they realized the issue, the workaround was to remove an element through its parent because when the element is gone, you are now simply holding a reference to the parent.  This would stop all that unpleasantness, and (if closing down a tree node by node, for example) would `'zip-up'` rather nicely.

It should be an easily fixable bug, but as with many other things in web programming, the release was probably rushed, leading to this... and by the time the next version came around, enough people were using it that changing this would lead to breaking a bunch of code.

Again, all of this is simply my guesswork.

I do, however, look forward to the day when web programming finally gets a full spring cleaning, all these strange little idiosyncracies get cleaned up, and everyone starts playing by the same rules.

Probably the day after my robot servant sues me for back wages.

Comment: I doubt that Firefox is responsible for this. `removeChild` is a method of the [DOM Level 1 `Node` interface](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/WD-DOM-Level-1-20000929/level-one-core.html#ID-1950641247).

Answer (score 1):

```
// http://javascript.crockford.com/memory/leak.html
// cleans dom element to prevent memory leaks
function domPurge(d) {
    var a = d.attributes, i, l, n;
    if (a) {
        for (i = a.length - 1; i >= 0; i -= 1) {
            n = a[i].name;
            if (typeof d[n] === 'function') {
                d[n] = null;
            }
        }
    }
    a = d.childNodes;
    if (a) {
        l = a.length;
        for (i = 0; i < l; i += 1) {
            domPurge(d.childNodes[i]);
       }
    }
}

function domRemove(id) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(id);
    domPurge(elem);
    return elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

This is the best function to remove an element without script error:

```
function Remove(EId)
{
    return(EObj=document.getElementById(EId))?EObj.parentNode.removeChild(EObj):false;
}
```

Note to `EObj=document.getElementById(EId)`.

This is ONE equal sign not `==`.

if element `EId` exists then the function removes it, otherwise it returns false, not `error`.

Comment: Creates a global variable.

Comment: It's also a worst version of [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3391282/1218980), but 2 years late.