# How to remove Div elements in javascript using their id?

Tags: javascript, dom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript: remove element by id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387427/javascript-remove-element-by-id)

I only know their respective ids and don't know specifically about their parent nodes....

Comment: if you dont want to use javascript because parent nodes then you should use jquery

Comment: @shareef jQuery uses parent nodes. jQuery is just a javascript function, you know.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15759882/jquery-finding-duplicate-ids-and-removing-all-but-the-first

Answer (score 28):

You can use `parentNode` on the element to get its parent, and use `removeChild` on it.

```
var el = document.getElementById( 'id' );
el.parentNode.removeChild( el );
```

Comment: Actually I am tring to remove the div elements of Google Hangouts Page, while loading my application.

Answer (score 22):

In jQuery, just `$('#your_id').remove();` will work.

Comment: +1 for showing how easy it's done with jQuery, even though the OP didn't ask for it. )

Comment: @raina77ow your statement says the following "congratulations for promoting a certain project" and "the OP didn't mention being able to use this library but what the heck +1 none the less". In other cases answers that require an external library that wasn't specifically asked for or accepted as a possibility by the op are downvoted.

Comment: Well, in my environment it's always beneficial to use some library instead of writing your own code - unless one has **very** strong reasons not to do so. Besides, I suppose the OP just begins to learn JavaScript: in that case studying jQuery as well will save him a LOT of time - as this answer clearly shows. If you want him to reinvent the wheel instead, good luck.

Comment: I'm using `$("#another-media["+data.id+"]").remove();` but it doesn't work