# How to know if two divs are present with same id in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any way to check if two divs are having same ids?

I have created divs dynamically and I am finding it difficult to remove the div having a duplicate id, can anyone help here?

Comment: id must be unique

Comment: "Should" be unique no? :)

Comment: Right, but the OP says they create the divs dynamically, the IDE won't help in such a case

Comment: @AyushiTomar use classes instead of id's on creating your dynamic content

Comment: Rather than `id`s you can use `data-` attributes

Comment: due to some reason i need to create the div using id's only .. any other suggestions?

Comment: `<div data-id="yourID">` on create dynamic content prehaps is a good idea, what do you need the id for?

Comment: This really sounds like an XY problem. You should be focusing on how or why duplicate ID's get created not how to remove them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know what you are trying to achieve here , but generally you should not have two elements with the same id . But if you have some reason to  do this maybe you are building a validator or someting like this  you can do the following to count the number of elements

```
var count = document.querySelectorAll('#test').length;

console.log(count);
```

then you can loop through them and remove them using

```
document.querySelectorAll('#test')[1].remove();
```

Comment: added how to remove them , since you know their count you can loop till it reaches their count-1 and remove them

Comment: Thanks, what if i want give some other id to that duplicate div ?

Comment: document.querySelectorAll('#test')[1].id = "another-id";

Comment: Cool , glad it helped please accept the answer as the correct one so others know that it worked for you :D

Answer (score 1):

Try it with:

```
        $('[id]').each(function () {
            var ids = $('[id=' + this.id + ']');
            if (ids.length > 1 && ids[0] == this) {
                $(ids[1]).remove();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop all the elements as helpers like `getElementById()` won't work well when their aren't unique.

Example, no need for jQuery. Alerts the duplicate ID.

```js
var idMap = {};

var all = document.getElementsByTagName("*");

for (var i=0; i < all.length; i++) {
     // Do something with the element here
     var elem = all[i];
     if(elem.id != ""){ //skip without id
       if(idMap[elem.id]){
          alert("'" + elem.id + "' is not unique")

       }
       idMap[elem.id] = true; 
     }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>

    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="id1"></div>
    <div id="id2"></div>
    <div id="id3"></div>
    <div id="id4"></div>
    <div id="id5"></div>
    <div id="id1"></div>
</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('[id]').each(function(){
    var ids = $('[id="'+this.id+'"]');
        if (ids.length>1 && ids[0]==this){
            $("#"+this.id).remove();
        }
 });​
```

above function use jquery to create array of all IDs with in the document and remove duplicated id

Comment: `$("#"+this.id).last()` does not make sense

Answer (score 0):

```
var idList = [];
$('*[id]').each(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    if($.inArray(id, idList)){
        alert('the id ' + id + ' is already set!');
    } else {
        idList.push(id);
    }
});
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation as well, not just code

Comment: @bc004346 search in each tag were id is set and check if the id allready in array. if it is in array, alert it else push the id to the array an go on. better?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do what you want

```js
$('[id]').each(function (i) {
    $('[id="' + this.id + '"]').slice(1).remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "1">
ola
</div>
<div id = "2">
ole
</div>
<div id = "1">
ola
</div>
<div id = "3">
olo
</div>
<div id = "1">
ola
</div>
<div id = "3">
olo
</div>
```

Example based on the link: [jQuery: Finding duplicate ID's and removing all but the first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15759882/jquery-finding-duplicate-ids-and-removing-all-but-the-first)

Answer (score -1):

Can you not just control + F and search for the id's? Also if you are using an editor like atom, you can delete every other duplicate in one go after the search.