# Removing element dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic

I'm trying to remove an element that I created dynamically.  This is how I created it...

```
var divTag = document.createElement("div");
divTag.id = "affiliation";
divTag.innerHTML = "Stuff Here";
```

I've tried several methods of removing it without success.  Here's what I have so far.

```
var A = document.getElementById('affiliation');
A.parentNode.removeChild(A);
```

Suggestions?

Comment: I'd rather do it pure javascript.  However, I'd love to hear any suggestions.

Comment: @user1612226 - are you sure that doesn't work? I do something like that all the time.

Comment: @user1612226 Updated the answer with both jQuery and Pure JavaScript way... :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript: remove element by id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387427/javascript-remove-element-by-id)

Comment: What you've got should work. Additionally, there's no need to re-query the DOM. Just use your original reference: `divTag.parentNode.removeChild(divTag);`

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but as per your code snippet, you never actually added the element to the DOM, so `A` will always be undefined.

Answer (score 1):

This snippet just works for me fine. The only difference is I added the "affiliation" divTag to the body

```
function insert() {
    var divTag = document.createElement("div");
    divTag.id = "affiliation";
    divTag.innerHTML = "Stuff Here";
    document.body.appendChild(divTag);
}
function remove() {
    var A = document.getElementById('affiliation');
    A.parentNode.removeChild(A);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to use **jQuery**, it is very easy to remove:

```
$("#affiliation").remove();
```

For the normal **JavaScript**, you can use this:

```
var node = document.getElementById("affiliation");
if (node.parentNode) {
    node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
}
```

Comment: maybe `$("#affiliation").remove();`

Answer (score 0):

Did you appended to the body or a parent?

```
var divTag = document.createElement("div");
divTag.id = "affiliation";
divTag.innerHTML = "Stuff Here";
document.body.appendChild(divTag);


element = document.getElementById("affiliation");
element.parentNode.removeChild(element);​
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [Node.removeChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.removeChild)

```
var A = document.getElementById("affiliation");
if (A.parentNode) {
    A.parentNode.removeChild(A);
}
```