# JQuery Prevent Data from Posting

Tags: jquery, html, dynamic-tables

I have a dynamic table in my registration page which only shows if the user selects "register more users". Basically they can use the table to register other people. However, if at the last minute they choose, "only register me" and click submitting, how do I prevent all the table data from posting?

Comment: can you post your code , what  you have tried so far, nobody can understand what you are trying to do..Howerver to prevent data from posting back to server use should use `return false;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might want to stop posting the values of text input fields dynamically generated by clicking on Register more users button. You can track all the input fields being added to the table and then once user click Register me button, you can call a javascript function which will remove the text inputs previously added by calling `removechild` funcion.

You can try [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387427/javascript-remove-element-by-id) to get better idea on how to remove the text input elements.

Hope this will help. Thanks