# how to delete a tag with js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

for example:

```
<ul>
    <li id="l1"></li>
    <li id="l2"></li>
    <li id="l3"></li>
    <li id="l4"></li>
    <li id="l5"></li>
</ul>
```

how can I remove a row?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387427/javascript-remove-element-by-id

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#l1').remove();  // To remove specific element that has id

$('li').remove();   // To remove all li's

$('.l1').remove();  // To remove elements with class l1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can remove:

```
/**
id is a variable that you can get from anywhere wish you
**/

$("#l"+id).remove();
```

**Other option more specific**

```
$("#l1").remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) jQuery function.

Try with: `$('#l1').remove();` for removing the single `li` element.