# How to remove existing menu items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, menu

I created menu using fg.menu.js once its loaded I want to remove the unwanted menu for which user dont have access.
for eg:-

```
<ul>
    <li> <a href="#">menu1</a>
        <ul>
            <li id="8000610"><a href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="javascript:setMenuItem('someaction')">Test1</a>
            </li>
            <li id="20247"><a href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="javascript:setMenuItem('someaction2')">Test2</a>
            </li>
            <li id="8000526"><a href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="javascript:setMenuItem('someaction3')">Test3</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Now after loading the menu I want to remove the Test2

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you use jQuery, it's as simple as $('#20247').remove();

With vanilla JS it's

```
element = document.getElementById("element-id");
element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
```

Also, use [search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387427/javascript-remove-element-by-id).

Comment: Thanks  $('#20247').remove() works just for info is this remove the element completely or just hide it? What if we need to bring it back.

Comment: It removes the element completely. Use .hide() to hide, .show() to show and .toggle() to toggle. All of these basic functions can be found in the jQuery api documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/