# Remove input element by ID with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, input

I have done this and it doesn't seem to be working!:

Javascript:

```
<script>
function hideOptionPhoto(){ 
    var element = document.getElementById("Photo1");
    element.parentNode.removeChild(Photo);   
};

window.onload = function() {
    hideOptionPhoto();
};
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div id=Photo1>
    <input id="Photo" type="image" src="x.png" border="0" name="submit" alt="">
</div>
```

I put the `<input>` inside a `<div>` because of the parent and child situation. Is that correct?

Comment: Even if `Photo` reference the `input` element, `Photo` is a child of `Photo1`, not of the *parent* of `Photo1`. Hence the `element.parentNode.removeChild(Photo);` won't work. [Learn how to **debug** JavaScript](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners).

Comment: @maxmitch Your HTML has a Syntax error in the first Line. CHeck my answer. Explanation included

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this out. This will work

The below script should be put inside the **body tag**

```
<script>
function hideOptionPhoto(){


var element = document.getElementById("Photo1");
var child=document.getElementById("Photo");
element.removeChild(child);

}
window.onload = function() {
  hideOptionPhoto();
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 6):

```
var element = document.getElementById("Photo"); // notice the change
element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
```

The `<div>` is optional (for this) since every element has a parentNode. But there might be other reasons for having the div.

Comment: plz see working jsfiddle. or see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387427/javascript-remove-element-by-id

Comment: Sorry I was using the live function on dreamweaver and doesn't seem to be working. Just putting it on the internet now to see if it works!

Comment: This is a very stupid question and irrelevant but is there an option other than `.onload` that does it earlier? And it doesn't seem to be working... Weird, as it is obviously working on jsfiddle! I have put it inside an if statement but I assume that won't make a difference?

Comment: You put put a small script immediately after the element. It can't execute earlier than that, or the element won't exist, and you won't be able to get a reference to it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Let me post the working fiddle and the I will give the explanation.

***[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PKqMT/972/)***

In your code there was a ***"Syntax Error"***.

```
//Incorrect    
     <div id=Photo1>

//Correct
    <div id="Photo1">
```

In addition check my JavaScript function. *The function call was ok.* Just the code inside it was wrong

You already assigned the ***HTMLelement div(Photo1)*** to the variable ***"Element"***.
The ***img("photo")*** is a **child** of Element and hence can be directly removed.

*One more important point is the naming conventions that you use. You should not assign ID's like "photo"*

HTML

```
<div id="Photo1">
    <input id="Photo" type="image" src="x.png" border="0" name="submit" alt=""/>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
function hideOptionPhoto(){     
    var element = document.getElementById("Photo1");
    var child=document.getElementById("Photo");
    element.removeChild(child);
};

window.onload = function() {
    hideOptionPhoto();
};
```

Comment: The OP isn't using XHTML, omitting the quotes around an attribute value consisting entirely of letters is not an error of any kind.

Comment: *You should not assign ID's like "photo"* — What is wrong with "photo" as an ID?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
function hideOptionPhoto(){ 
var element =  document.getElementById('Photo');
if (typeof(element) != 'undefined' && element != null)
  {
    element.remove();
    alert('Deleted');
  }

};

window.onload = function() {
    hideOptionPhoto();
};
```

```html
<div id=Photo1>
    <input id="Photo" type="image" src="x.png" border="0" name="submit" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<div id="Photo1">
<input id="Photo" type="image" src="x.png" border="0" name="submit" alt="">
</div>
```

Use this:

```
document.getElementById("Photo1").innerHTML = "";
```