# Object doesn't support property or method 'remove'

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I know there is some issue with get `document.getElementById` and IE, but not sure why IE is having a problem with `.remove` and all other browsers are not. Any help here would be appreciated. I am getting the error

```
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'remove'
```

from the error console. The Javascript works in all other browsers.
Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
function removeModule() {

    <?php $tab = 1; ?>
    var module_row = <?php echo $module_row; ?>;

    if(!confirm('Are you sure?'))
    {
        return false;
    }

        var x = 1;
        while (x < module_row)
        {
            if (document.getElementById('tab-' + x).checked)
            {           
                document.getElementById('tab-' + x).remove();
                document.getElementById('module-' + x).remove();
                document.getElementById('tab-module-' + x).remove();
            }
            x++;
            <?php $tab++; ?>
        }
        $('#form').submit();

}
//--></script>
```

This is from an opencart module, it is the tpl file. I've included part of the file here as well so hopefully someone can spot whatever the error is.

```
<?php echo $header; ?>
<div id="content">
    <div class="breadcrumb">
        <?php foreach ($breadcrumbs as $breadcrumb) { ?>
            <?php echo $breadcrumb['separator']; ?><a href="<?php echo $breadcrumb['href']; ?>"><?php echo $breadcrumb['text']; ?></a>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
    <?php if ($error_warning) { ?>
        <div class="warning"><?php echo $error_warning; ?></div>
    <?php } ?>
    <div class="box">
    <div class="heading">
        <h1><img src="view/image/module.png" alt="" /> <?php echo $heading_title; ?></h1>
        <div class="buttons">
            <a onclick="$('#form').submit();" class="button"><?php echo $button_save; ?></a>

            <a onclick="removeModule();" class="button"><?php echo $button_delete ?></a>            

            <a onclick="location = '<?php echo $cancel; ?>';" class="button"><?php echo $button_cancel; ?></a></div>
        </div>

        <div class="content">
            <form action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form">
            <div class="vtabsQS">
                <?php $module_row = 1; ?>               
                <?php foreach ($modules as $module) 
                {  ?>
                <div style="margin-left: -7px; float:left;">
                    <input type="checkbox" style="float: left; margin-top: 8px;" id="tab-<?php echo $module_row; ?>" onClick="" value="#tab-<?php echo $module_row; ?>"  />                 
                    <a href="#tab-module-<?php echo $module_row; ?>" id="module-<?php echo $module_row; ?>">
                        <?php foreach ($languages as $language) 
                        { ?> 
                            <label class="inputLrgTab"><?php if (!empty($module['language_id'][$language['language_id']])) { echo $module['language_id'][$language['language_id']];} ?></label> 
                        <?php } ?>                                      
                    </a><br />          
                </div>              
                <?php $module_row++; ?>
                <?php } ?>
                <span id="module-add" style="clear: both; margin-left: -7px;"><?php echo $button_add_module; ?>&nbsp;<img src="view/image/add.png" alt="" onclick="addModule();" /></span>
            </div>          


        <?php $module_row = 1; ?>
        <?php foreach ($modules as $module) { ?>
        <div id="tab-module-<?php echo $module_row; ?>" class="vtabs-content" style="margin-left:230px;">
          <table class="form">
            <tr>
              <td><?php echo $entry_title; ?></td>
              <td class="left">
                <?php foreach ($languages as $language) { ?>
                <img src="view/image/flags/<?php echo $language['image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $language['name']; ?>" />
                <input class="inputLrg" type="text" name="<?php echo $classname; ?>_module[<?php echo $module_row; ?>][language_id][<?php echo $language['language_id']; ?>]" value="<?php if (!empty($module['language_id'][$language['language_id']])) { echo $module['language_id'][$language['language_id']];} ?>">
                <br />
                <?php } ?>
                <span class="error"><?php echo $error_title; ?></span>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><?php echo $entry_limit; ?></td>
```

Comment: It's not supported in IE https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode.remove

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387427/javascript-remove-element-by-id

Comment: IE10 gives a fat error if .remove() is used..I am surprised this version is fairly modern and doesn't support this!

Comment: see the pure vanilla javascript solution below

Answer (score 48, accepted):

[`remove()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode.remove) as a method on HTMLElements unfortunately is [not supported by Internet Explorer](http://caniuse.com/#search=remove).

You could use the workaround in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18120786/1047823) for a vanilla javascript solution.

However as you already seem to use jQuery, instead replace

```
document.getElementById('tab-' + x).remove();
```

with

```
$('#tab-' + x).remove();
```

Comment: Took you suggestion and replaced with: 
 $('#tab-' + x).remove();
 $('#module-' + x).remove();
 $('#tab-module-' + x).remove(); 

and now it works!

Comment: @Bryan you are welcome. If this worked for you, you can mark this answer as solution so everybody knows that your issues has been solved.

Answer (score 50):

You should get the parent of the element you are trying to remove and use the remove child method to find and remove the element

```
element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
```

this works in all browsers including IE.

Comment: parentElement was coming up null in IE11, but parentNode (as here) worked fine. Thanks! This should be accepted as the best answer because it is fast and does not use any other libraries and does not search the document tree.

Comment: Thanks @dean for the feedback

Comment: Very elegant, clean and vanilla.

Comment: I like this more than the accepted answer that uses jQuery. This vanilla Javascript better is so much cleaner.

Answer (score 12):

You should use this

```
element.parentElement.removeChild(element);
```

Supported by all browser and also have some benefits over just a hack to 
    remove child element.

**Here is another workaround for keep using `.remove()` function**

```
Element.prototype.remove = function() {
    this.parentElement.removeChild(this);
}
NodeList.prototype.remove = HTMLCollection.prototype.remove = function() {
    for(var i = this.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if(this[i] && this[i].parentElement) {
            this[i].parentElement.removeChild(this[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

And then you can remove elements like this

```
document.getElementById("my-element").remove();
```

or

```
document.getElementsByClassName("my-elements").remove();
```

[Here is Stack Overflow link for further info also source of this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387427/remove-element-by-id/18120786#18120786)

Answer (score 4):

It appears that IE10 also throws this error..

Here one way I tried using the objects `outerHTML` property:

```
    if(typeof document.getElementById('id').remove=='function'){
       //If support  is found 
        document.getElementById('id').remove()
    }
    else{
      //If not
       document.getElementById('id').outerHTML='';
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can polyfill the remove() method:

```
(function (arr) {
  arr.forEach(function (item) {
    if (item.hasOwnProperty('remove')) {
      return;
    }
    Object.defineProperty(item, 'remove', {
      configurable: true,
      enumerable: true,
      writable: true,
      value: function remove() {
        this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
      }
    });
  });
})([Element.prototype, CharacterData.prototype, DocumentType.prototype]);
```