# how to remove child div using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

this my html

```
<div>
    <div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
</div>
```

this my script

```
var list=document.getElementById("div2");
list.removeChild("div2""));
```

when i click the buttton i need to remove the child div(div2)  how to do that. using this code i am facing problem please tell. help me . we have any other solution for this problem

Comment: Asked so many times http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387427/javascript-remove-element-by-id You should search before you ask.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you have double quotes and double braces at the end. And I'm not sure what you're trying to do. If you'd like to remove element with the id "div2", use:

```
var list=document.getElementById("div2");
list.parentNode.removeChild(list);
```

Comment: Do you have any idea regarding not to remove rather detach a concerned div.?

Answer (score 3):

You need to find `div2` parent and then you can use `removeChild` to remve `div2`

```
var list=document.getElementById("div2");
var parentDiv = list.parentNode;
parentDiv.removeChild(list);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vEpAt/1/)

Problem in your code

```
list.removeChild("div2"")); <<== ") is additional
```

Comment: What's the difference between your answer and what I have posted earlier?

Comment: @SamBraslavskiy, Its not different but I was working on demo while you posted and I assure you its not copied

Comment: Totally believe you. Liked your answer, since we're at some degree like-minded)

Answer (score 2):

Use modern JS!

```
const div = document.getElementById("div2");
div.remove();
```

or just

```
document.getElementById("div2").remove()
```

Answer (score 0):

try removing the elements like this

```
//HTML MARKUP

<div id="div1">
<div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
</div>

//Javascript
var list=document.getElementById('div1');

list.removeChild(list.getElementById('div2'));
```