# Remove parent div when page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have HTML like :

```
<div id="parent">
 <ul class="list">something here....</ul>
</div>
```

When page load, I want kill div that have id="parent". That means after finish the loading, I have only :

```
<ul class="list">something here....</ul>
```

How Javascript or Jquery can do this? Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you're looking to kill the div on page load, why have it in the first place?

Comment: smarter way is : don't put `parent div` even on page load :)

Comment: It is my issue with "absolute" property and responsive design. It conflicts with many components so my solution is removing it. Thanks for your good ask.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/

Comment: Thanks for all enthusiastic answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try:

```
$(function() {
    $("ul.list").unwrap();
});
```

[Docs for `unwrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/).

Comment: May it is what i am looking for. I will do it with your method. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try this famous code to completely remove div:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
    var element = document.getElementById("parent");
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
},false);
```

[remove element by id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387427/javascript-remove-element-by-id)

And to remove only parent div use jQuery's unwrap:

```
$(function() {
    $("ul.list").unwrap();
});
```

OR in plain javascript:

```
  function unwrap() {
            var a = document.getElementById('element-to-be-unwrapped');
            newelement = a.firstElementChild.cloneNode();
            document.body.insertBefore(newelement, a);
            a.parentNode.removeChild(a);
  }
```

Comment: Yeah, but it will also remove the contents of the div.

Answer (score 1):

in jQuery, here is the code:

```
var ul_holder = $('#parent').html();
$('#parent').remove();
$(document).append(ul_holder);
```

You can replace $(document) with any other element

Answer (score 1):

Use [.unwrap()](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) function

```
  if (  $(".list").parent('#parent').is( "div" ) ) {
     $(".list").unwrap();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest) with [remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove)

```
$(function() {
    $("ul.list").closest('#parent').remove();
});
```

or you can use [unwrap()](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap) like,

```
$(function() {
    $("ul.list").unwrap();
});
```