# Remove elements slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slideshow, removechild

I try to remove my links one by one from `div id="wrapper"`. But it doesn't work:

```
window.onload = function () {
  setInterval(function () {
    var wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper");
    var my_links = wrapper.getElementsByTagName("a");

    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < my_links.lenght + 1; i++) {
      my_links.splice(0, i);
    }
  }, 5000);
}
```

What is the problem? How can i fix my snippet?

Comment: Please try checking your error console in your browser's Dev Tools before posting a question.

Answer (score 1):

Typo here and length + 1 should be length - 1:

```
for (i=0; i<my_links.lenght+1; i++){
```

should be:

```
for (i=0; i<my_links.length-1; i++){
```

**Further more**

Look at this question over here to find the remove function you are looking for: [Remove element by id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387427/javascript-remove-element-by-id)

So it will be:

```
for (i=0; i<my_links.length-1; i++){
    my_links[i].remove();
}
```

Remove function only works with the function of the question I posted.