# Comment using HTML and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, comments

I have a task to create like comment box in the HTML and Javascript
How to delete comment using button delete?
or should i use linked list in this task?
This is my code:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id='container'>
            <textarea id='txt'></textarea><br/>
            <button type='button' onclick="add()">Enter</button>
            <div id='contents'></div>
        </div>

        <script>
            function add(){
                var txt= document.getElementById('txt').value;
                var content= document.getElementById('contents');
                var tes= '<hr/><span>'+txt+"</span><button type='button'>delete</button>";
                content.innerHTML+=tes;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question quick, if you wanna stick with pure javascript, you can remove element from DOM using his Parent, take a look at this
[Remove element by id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387427/javascript-remove-element-by-id)

P.S Don't you need a way to store your comments somewhere (database?)

P.S.2 You should avoid using html tags directly in a string assigned to a variable. Maybe you should take a look at some best practice over the web (regarding DOM manipulation, jQuery clone() method etc)

Hope it helps

Comment: no i dont need database for this.
this is some test i got.
and i can't use jquery.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you're not worried about persisting your data. So the quickest fix would be:

```
   <script>
            var arr = 1;
            function del(comm_id){
               var dom =document.getElementById(comm_id);
               dom.parentNode.removeChild(dom);
            }

        function add(){
            var txt= document.getElementById('txt').value;
            var content= document.getElementById('contents');
            var comm_id="comment"+arr;
            var del_id="delete"+arr;
            var tes= "<div id="+comm_id+">"+'<hr/><span>'+txt+"</span><button type='button' id="+ del_id + ">delete</button></div>";
            content.innerHTML+=tes;
             document.getElementById(del_id).setAttribute('onclick',"del('"+comm_id+"')");
            arr++;
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: if i do that it would make the deleted comment only deleted the last one.

Answer (score 0):

For this there is no need of implementing Linked List. You can make use of Array in javascript. There is no need of pre-defining the size of array. You can add any number of elements in it.

To remove a particular element you can make use of

```
array.splice(i, 1);
```

This will remove the ith element.