# Delete hidden input field by id through javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3

How to delete Hidden Input field using its id through JavaScript in Rails?

Thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript: remove element by id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387427/javascript-remove-element-by-id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use jQuery:

```
$('#id').remove()
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter what's the backend technology here ;) To remove element by its id you should do it that way:

```
var element = document.getElementById("element-id");
element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387427/javascript-remove-element-by-id