# How jquery remove function works?

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery uses the script like this:

```
function remove() {
jQuery("*", this).add([this]).each(function () {
jQuery.event.remove(this);
jQuery.removeData(this);
});
if (this.parentNode)
this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
}
```

As far as I understand the code is removing the element if the element has parentNode but I wanted to know why does it removes the element which have no parentNode:

```
$('html').remove();//html has no parentNode but html is removed
```

Sorry, if I'm one that couldn't understand this script, please make my concept clear. Thank you.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387427/javascript-remove-element-by-id

Comment: As per my understanding `document` is parent of `HTML` tag. Just try `$('html').parent()` in your browser console

Comment: I recommend this blog article: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1822-learning-jquery-1-4-remove-vs-detach.htm

Comment: @Satpal but what if $('*').remove(); it removes all, document too????

Comment: I have never used `$(document).remove();`, so can't help you on that. Lets see what I can find? EDIT: `$(document).remove();` doesn't remove document. However `$('*').remove();` removes all child element of document but document. In short `document` is never removed