# How to Hide or remove dom?

Tags: dom, dojo

i'm using

```
var btn = dom.byId("portAid");
btn.innerHTML=omsportAid;
btn.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
```

How to remove/hide the div(portAid)?

Comment: Have you tried `btn.style.display = 'none'`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript: remove element by id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387427/javascript-remove-element-by-id)

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate:
[Remove element by id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387427/javascript-remove-element-by-id)

```
var element = document.getElementById("portAid");
element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove it:

```
btn.style.display="none";
```

Or to simply hide it:

```
btn.style.visibility="hidden";
```

The difference is that with visibility: hidden the component will still take up space, but it will be invisible. Display:none removes the component and collapses the other components that surround it on the now empty space.