# How to merge <ol> tag using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

How to merge these two `<ol>` tags using javascript ?

Here is my code:

```
<ol id="myList1">
    <li>Apple</li>
    <li>Pear</li>
    <li>Peach</li>
</ol>
<ol id="myList2">
    <li>Orange</li>
</ol>
```

Output:

```
<ol id="myList1">
   <li>Apple</li>
   <li>Pear</li>
   <li>Peach</li>
   <li>Orange</li>
</ol>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you want to merge the tags? Do you want to create a new tag containing the children of both, or do you want to move the children into the first or last element?

Answer (score 1):

Vanilla JS variant:

```
var list1    = document.getElementById('myList1'),
    list2    = document.getElementById('myList2'),
    children = list2.childNodes // select all children nodes from one element
    i, item;

// Add each children to list1
for (i = 0; item = children[i]; i++) {
    list1.appendChild(item);
}

// Remove list2 DOMElement
list2.parentNode.removeChild(list2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(function(){
  var otherLis = $("#myList2").find("li").detach(); // this will detach li's from second OL
  $("#myList1").append(otherLis); // this will appeend them to first OL
}())
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/coloqepi/1/edit)

Comment: The OP didn't tag this post with jQuery, so I'm assuming a standard JS solution is preferred. Also, some explanation never hurts.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in pure javascript:

```
var a = document.getElementById('myList1');
var b = document.getElementById('myList2');
a.innerHTML = a.innerHTML + b.innerHTML;
b.remove();
```

First get the list elements of both lists and then concatenate, and then add to the new list;

Comment: atleast comment when you downvote how would i know my mistake

Comment: Well,  I'm not the one who down voted but I thought I'd mention that you forgot to remove the second `ol`.  You can do `document.getElementById('myList2').remove();` in the end.

Comment: Yes I agree,  but like I said,  I'm not the one who down-voted your answer.  Cheers!

Comment: krgaurav: Sorry for not leaving comment right away. My bad. The reason is that you should use native DOM manipulation methods not string concentration.

Answer (score 0):

While not that elegant, there's a simple solution in pure JS:

```
document.getElementById("myList1").innerHTML += document.getElementById("myList2").innerHTML;

document.getElementById("myList2").remove();
```

It just takes adds the contents of `myList2` to `myList1` and removes `myList2`: not too much to explain there.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/AstroCB/Wdcn3/)

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
document.querySelector('#myList1').appendChild(document.querySelector("#myList2>li"));
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z7qaH/)

Comment: This will still have an empty `<ol id="myList2"></ol>` in HTML or am i missing something?

Comment: yeah that you can easily remove with another javascript snippet!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387427/javascript-remove-element-by-id