# dynamically removing elements from form using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

my html div part is

```
<div id="upload">

<input type="button" id="add" value="Click here to add" onclick="uploadFile();">

<input type="hidden" name="fileCount" id="fileCount" value="0" />
</div>
```

my javascript is

```
function uploadFile()
{
    var count = parseInt($('#fileCount').val(), 10);
    count = count + 1;
    if(count<=2){
        var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
        var br = document.createElement("br");
        var text = document.createElement("INPUT");
        var remove = document.createElement("INPUT");
        text.setAttribute("type", "text");
        text.setAttribute("name", "description_" + count);
        text.setAttribute("value", "file description");
        remove.setAttribute("type", "button");
        remove.setAttribute("value", "Delete");
        remove.setAttribute("id", "Delete"+count);
        remove.setAttribute("onclick", "remove();");

        x.setAttribute("type", "file");
        x.setAttribute("name", "file_" + count);
        x.setAttribute("id", "file_" + count);

        x.setAttribute("onchange","checkFile(this);");
        upload.appendChild(br);
        upload.appendChild(x);
        upload.appendChild(text);
        upload.appendChild(remove);
        $('#fileCount').val(count);
    }
    else{
        alert("cant upload more than two files");
    }
}

function remove()
{
    //  upload.getElementById(file_).remove();
}
```

Here I need a remove function for deleting the corresponding element when I click `Delete` button dynamically.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387427/javascript-remove-element-by-id
check this

Answer (score 0):

call this function on click of the button.

`function removeDummy() {
    var elem = document.getElementById('elementtodelete');
    elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
    return false;
}`

Answer (score -1):

You can use jQuery `remove()` method which delete the elements from HTML and DOM.

```
$(selector).remove();
```

jQuery remove method ref: [remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)