# Using Javascript to remove/hide span tags that have a certain class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm writing some software that compiles HTML fragments and exports them to Microsoft Word. I'd like a script that cycles through the compiled fragments and removes certain tags that have a particular class.

I cannot use CSS as the display:none; style doesn't work on export to Word.

I cannot use a tags id as the fragments may have multiple instances of tags I want to hide.

This is what I have so far:

```
<head>
<script>
    function hideme(){  
        var span = document.getElementById("hideme");
        span.parentNode.removeChild(span);  
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="hideme()">
    Hello I'd like to remove <span id="hideme" value="1">THIS</span> word, which I can<br/>
    I'd also like to remove <span id="hideme" value="1">THIS</span> word, which I can't
</body>
```

Comment: Id should be unique.!

Comment: $('.className').hide() or $('.className').remove()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The id need unique, so change id to class

```
<head>
<script>
    function hideme(){  
        var span = document.getElementsByClassName("hideme");
        span.parentNode.removeChild(span);  
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="hideme()">
    Hello I'd like to remove <span class="hideme" value="1">THIS</span> word, which I can<br/>
    I'd also like to remove <span class="hideme" value="1">THIS</span> word, which I can't
</body>
```

It very simple with jquery

```
<body>
        Hello I'd like to remove <span class="hideme" value="1">THIS</span> word, which I can<br/>
        I'd also like to remove <span class="hideme" value="1">THIS</span> word, which I can't
    </body>
```

script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".hideme").hide(); //or $(".hideme").remove();
});
```

Comment: I was aware that the id has to be unique and probably shouldn't have included my example demonstrating this. 
This is what I was after, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

using `Javascript` you can use: 
[**javascript-remove-element-by-id**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387427/javascript-remove-element-by-id)

using `jQuery`:

```
$('#hideme').hide() // hides element diplay:none
```

or

```
$('#hideme').remove()  // removes element
```