# how to delete input text box from javascript

Tags: javascript

i have created a input text box from javascript with the following code in runtime

```
var textbox = document.createElement('input');

textbox.type = 'text';

textbox.id='tbox';
textbox.value=document.getElementById("texts"+i).value;

document.getElementById('frm').appendChild(textbox);
```

How can i delete the same textbox in runtime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In javascript, you can not directly remove the element. You have to go to its parent element to remove it.

```
var elem = document.getElementById("tbox");
elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById('frm').removeChild(document.getElementById('tbox'));
```

Answer (score 0):

try `remove()`

so assuming I've got the right one:

```
document.getElementById("texts"+i).remove()
```

If not the above... then make sure you give it an id and choose it by that before `remove()`ing it

Comment: ... which won't work for browsers not implementing DOM level 4 (most IE versions)

Comment: ...which wasn't specified in the question, but sure.

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate: [Remove element by id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387427/javascript-remove-element-by-id)

However you can use the following solution:

You could make a function that did the removing for you so that you wouldn't have to think about it every time.

```
function remove(id)
{
    return (elem=document.getElementById(id)).parentNode.removeChild(elem);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var temp = document.getElementById('texts'+i);
           temp.parentNode.removeChild(temp);
```