# How can I remove a created createDocumentFragment object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In a function I create often DocumentFragment-object, therefore I like to remove it after the process is finish.
DocumentFragment has no parent, therefore I can't use e.g.:

```
node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
```

Or e.g. using jQuery as follows:

```
var oDocFrag = document.createDocumentFragment();
alert($(oDocFrag).length); // shows 1
$(oDocFrag).remove(); 
alert($(oDocFrag).length); // still shows 1
```

Any idea how can I remove a created DocumentFragment-object?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you can just assign it `null` e.g. `oDocFrag = null;`. It doesn't persist in the DOM.

Comment: OK. I hope it will be enough. Thanks.

Comment: And why would you need to remove the entire fragment ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rather set it to null or empty:

```
 oDocFrag = null;
```

Comment: OK. I hope it will be enough. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
oDocFrag.remove();
```

it works for me.

refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387427/remove-element-by-id?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: And what it actually does?

Comment: remove it oDocFrag dom element from dom tree.

Comment: But the `document fragment` doesn't get appended to the DOM.

Comment: @Suresh Mahawar element.remove(). This works in WebKit and Firefox, but not IE. DocumentFragment has no parent!!!

Comment: Guys, what are you talking about? Here is an example: http://codepen.io/karlen/pen/yyoBWz Inspect the DOM and find your `document fragment` *to remove*.