# Element.prototype.remove - Closure Compiler warning

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

I am using this solution: (from: [Remove element by id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387427/remove-element-by-id))

```
Element.prototype.remove = function() {
    this.parentElement.removeChild(this);
}
NodeList.prototype.remove = HTMLCollection.prototype.remove = function() {
    for(var i = 0, len = this.length; i < len; i++) {
        if(this[i] && this[i].parentElement) {
            this[i].parentElement.removeChild(this[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the following warning in closure compiler:

`externs.zip//w3c_dom2.js:793: WARNING - mismatch of the remove property type and the type of the property it overrides from superclass Element
original: function (this:Element): undefined
override: function (this:HTMLSelectElement, number): undefined
HTMLSelectElement.prototype.remove = function(index) {};`

How can I clear this warning? Or should I use another approach for element.remove?

Comment: Easiest solution - just chose a different function name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler is warning you that a class which inherits from `Element` already has a method named `remove` and that it's signature doesn't match yours. In this case, the [HTMLSelectElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/remove).

Were you to ignore the warning, your remove method would not function correctly for `HTMLSelectElement` elements - as that function performs a very different behavior from what you defined.

The comment by @php_nub_qq is correct. Choose a method name that does not conflict with existing objects in the inheritance chain.

Comment: Notice that `HTMLSelectElement::remove` is overloaded - if called without an index, it is indeed equivalent to [`Node::remove`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove). Polyfillying that should respect this of course, but using a different method name is not really an option. I wonder how GCC can deal with overloaded methods though.

Comment: I had missed the new `ChildNode` interface. Closure-compiler doesn't currently recognize/implement that interface. I'll see about getting this worked in. That will resolve the issue.