# How to remove the content from a "div" element using a button "onclick" function?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `div` element that contains a number of images. When the user clicks a button, I want the contents of the `div` to be removed (not the `div` itself, I want to reuse the `div` to potentially add new content).

In my HTML, the `div` and `button` are defined as:

```
<body>
    ...
    <div class="MyDiv"></div>
    ...
    <button id="removeDiv" onclick="removeDivFunction()">remove Div Function</button>
    ...
</body>
```

How do I write a function that removes all elements from this `div`?

Comment: jQuery solution or no?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove element by id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387427/remove-element-by-id)

Comment: http://red-team-design.com/removing-an-element-with-plain-javascript-remove-method/

Comment: `div.innerHTML = ""` is that what you want?

Comment: To the author: I edited both title and content of your question so that it becomes more immediately apparent what you are looking for. Remember that the more clearly you state your question, the more chance you have that someone will go through the trouble of answering it. Also, if your question was answered correctly, *please* remember to 'approve' the correct answer. This rewards the author of that answer and makes it easier for future visitors to see what the correct answer was.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call [`removeChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild):

```
function removeDivFunction() {
   MyDiv.parentNode.removeChild(MyDiv);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="div1" style="height:100px;width:300px;border:1px solid black;background-color:yellow;">

This is some text in the div.
<p>This is a paragraph in the div.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph in the div.</p>

</div>
<br>

<button>Remove div element</button>


$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#div1").remove();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function removeDivFunction() {
    $(".MyDiv").remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

David has already pointed you to an existing question/solution.
For reference consider reading: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_nodes.asp
Its always a good idea to assign id to the div.

Also if you are using jQuery you can delete element by $("#divid").remove() for reference see: https://api.jquery.com/remove/

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="MyDiv">I need to remove</div>
<button id="removeDiv" onclick="removeDivFunction()">remove Div Function</button>  
function removeDivFunction() {
    var element = document.getElementsByClassName("MyDiv")[0];
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gf3aLgc7/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can try
Html

```
<div id="some">Example</div>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

javascript

```
function myFunction() {
    var child = document.getElementById("some");
    child.parentNode.removeChild(child);
}
```

And if you want to erase content of DIV then use

```
  child.innerHTML = "";
```