# how to remove html element dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two functions in mycode.first is `addElement()` and second is `removeElement()`
When I click on add it is adding elements dynamically, Now what I want to remove  those elements dynamically when I click on remove.
I tried `.remove()` and `.empty()` but its not working.
Please help.
add code:

```
$('#original').append('<br/><br/><strong>And &nbsp; </strong>');
                        var content = '<select name=selParameter' + count + ' id=selParameter' + count + ' class=chosen-select><option value=0>Select Parameter</option>';
```

remove code: `$('#original').remove('#selParameter' + count + '');`

Comment: Show the add and remove code.

Comment: Post your code fro add and remove functionality

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove element by id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387427/remove-element-by-id)

Comment: Have you tried `$('#selParameter' + count).remove()`?

Comment: yes I tried it but its not working

Comment: i'd suggest making a fiddle of your solution and then we can better understand the problem

Comment: The 'add' code provided does not add the 'content' to the DOM.  So there's nothing to remove.  Please add the correct code or (as per other comment) create a jsfiddle where the add does add the elements correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is you are adding the content to the HTML page after page is loaded, the same will work if you have done before the page load.

There is on function in jQuery to record changes and remove the elements dynamically when they are added. Please have a look at the following documentation http://api.jquery.com/on/

Let me know, if you still face issues.

Comment: which event am I suppose to use like load or else

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
$("#add").on('click', function(){
    alert('add');
 $('body').append("<p id='added'> this is added </p>")
})

$('#remove').on('click', function(){
 alert('remove');
    $('#added').remove()
})
});