# .remove() not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser

This code works very well in Google Chrome, but wont work in Internet Explorer:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('info')[i].remove();
```

Is there some other method to do the same thing or can I make `.remove()` work in Internet Explorer?

Comment: As you've tagged jQuery why not use that, and forget worrying about browser specific faults; `$('.info').eq(i).remove();`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387427/remove-element-by-id

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[remove is not supported by ie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove#Browser_compatibility)

You would have to get the parent and call removeChild

```
var node = document.getElementsByClassName('info')[i];
node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
```

Also since you have jQuery tagged you could just do

```
jQuery(".info").eq(i).remove()
```

as jQuery does cross browser checks and uses the correct methods