# Remove Element When Page is Viewed using Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I have the following bit of code shown below:

```
<div class="timer" id="timer"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/87XaOWA.png"><p class="close-message" id="close-message"></p></div>
```

Now, when the page is viewed in Internet Explorer I want the `div` to be removed.

Since [IE doesn't support the .remove() function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove#Browser_compatibility) I have found the following solution to circumvent the problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32670868/6668929). I have also found the following [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/311aLtkz/) that can detect which browser is being used to view the page.

I've tried the following two `if` statements to remove the `div` tag when viewed in IE to no avail:

```
// Internet Explorer 6-11
var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document.documentMode

if (isIE = false) {
jQuery("#timer").eq(i).remove();
}
```

and

```
// Internet Explorer 6-11
var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document.documentMode

if (isIE = false) {
var node = document.getElementsById('timer')[i];
node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Individually the two components work fine, but when I try to use them together they don't work.

Comment: it should be **if(isIE == false)**

Comment: @TemaniAfif you mean it **should** be ?

Comment: yes, i meant i shouldn' be = :)

Comment: Hi. first what is the `i` why you dont just do second why you want to use them both ? you all ready remove it on the first time

Comment: you are confusing people saying it's related to IE, but it's simply syntax errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first error is:

```
if (isIE = false) {
```

you need to use a double equal sign for comparing, and in your case it should be:

```
if (isIE == true) {
```

The second error is:

```
document.getElementsById('timer')[i]
```

change it to:

```
document.getElementById('timer')
```

```js
var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document.documentMode;

if (isIE == true) {
    var node = document.getElementById('timer');
    node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
}

//
// in jQuery: remove: .eq(i)....
//
if (isIE == true) {
  jQuery("#timer").remove();
}
```

```html
<div class="timer" id="timer"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/87XaOWA.png"><p class="close-message" id="close-message"></p></div>
```

Comment: Guess I didn't catch my `isIE = false` mistake because my JS wasn't inside the `div` tag in my code which contains the `#timer`. But for whatever reason while this works in my code it doesn't work in JSFiddle which if it had worked I might of caught my mistake before posting this question.

Comment: @ChippeRockTheMurph You may consider to wrap your code in [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded).