# Parsing HTML out of <object> tag with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, parsing, object

I have the following HTML tag:

```
<object type="text/html" data="/page.html"></object>
```

I need to strip out an element from the HTML that is being generated. I try with this:

```
var mainFrame = '<object type="text/html" data="/page.html"></object>'; 
html = $.parseHTML(mainFrame),
console.log(html);
```

but i'm only getting an object containing:

```
<object data="/page.html" type="text/html"></object>
```

**UPDATE**

I'm expecting to get the `page.html` HTML. Like:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div id="elementToStripOut"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then I need to remove the div `#elementToStripOut`.

Comment: What output are you expecting? You say you want to strip out an element from the HTML string, but the string only contains one element... ?

Comment: Is object url  on same domain as page? If not you probably can't access the inner window it creates

Comment: Likewise I have the same questions as Rory McCrossan - what output are you expecting?

Comment: I'm expecting the HTML of the page that is being included. I'm on the same domain.

Comment: @l736k so you want to get the HTML of `page.html`, not the `object` element?

Comment: Given your update, why not use AJAX instead of the `object` element?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan it's not something i can choose

Comment: In that case I'm not sure it's possible to access the HTML within the object via JS.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes it is. I can access it from the JS console, once the page is fully loaded, with `$('body').contents().find('object').get(0).contentWindow.document`

Comment: Well if you can do that, it's just a case of removing the element you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387427/remove-element-by-id

Answer (score 0):

I've never done this with `<object>` but assume principles should be the same as with an `<iframe>`

```
$('object').on('load',function(){
    $(this).contents().find('#elementToStripOut').remove();
});
```

Comment: this is returning `Object[object]` like i was doing before

Comment: The object is generating the full page.html, like an `<iframe>`. The code you posted is returning only the `<object data="/page.html" type="text/html"></object>`

Comment: i can't choose the html structure

Comment: could replace it with iframe `$('object').replaceWith(...`

Comment: i have actually access to the HTML code and i can modify it, but i am not allowed to do it.

Comment: what is full description of `not allowed to`?

Comment: the project owner doens't want to

Comment: well if you can't access it as `<object>` replace it with iframe which will let you in