# how to remove div from page so that it not appear in source code ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

How to remove div element form html page using jquery after loading so that it will not appear in source code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't. Modifying the DOM will never modify the original source code. Perhaps you should explain *why* you want to do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove element by id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387427/remove-element-by-id)

Comment: To get it straigt: You don't want to remove it from the source code but from the DOM structure. If you want to remove it from source, just delete it from the source file ;)

Comment: If you don't include it in the original source and instead add it on load and then remove it, then the user won't see it in the source. But like Mike said, it'd help if we knew what you were trying to accomplish.