# How can remove next cell in table using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I have the code below:

```js
   function colspan(){
     var x = document.getElementById("Cell2");
     x.setAttribute("colspan", 2);
     x.next().remove();
     }
```

```html
     <table border="1">
     <tr>
     <td id="Cell1">Cell 1</td>
     <td id="Cell2">Cell 2</td>
     <td id="Cell3">Cell 3</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td id="Cell4">Cell 4</td>
     <td id="Cell5">Cell 5</td>
     <td id="Cell6">Cell 6</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td id="Cell7">Cell 7</td>
     <td id="Cell8">Cell 8</td>
     <td id="Cell9">Cell 9</td>
     </tr>
     </table>
     
     <input type="button" onclick="colspan();" value="Change"/>
```

I would like to delete the next cell of the current cell I have called. When the Cell 2 is colspan, the Cell 3 should be removed, but I use `.next().remove()` is not working. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something you could do.

```js
function colspan() {
  var ele = document.getElementById("Cell2");
  ele.setAttribute("colspan", 2);
  if (ele.nextElementSibling) {
    ele.nextElementSibling.remove();
  }
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td id="Cell1">Cell 1</td>
    <td id="Cell2">Cell 2</td>
    <td id="Cell3">Cell 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="Cell4">Cell 4</td>
    <td id="Cell5">Cell 5</td>
    <td id="Cell6">Cell 6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="Cell7">Cell 7</td>
    <td id="Cell8">Cell 8</td>
    <td id="Cell9">Cell 9</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<input type="button" onclick="colspan();" value="Change" />
```

Comment: Yours one work better, since I work with JavaSricpt, it is better for me to work only one language rather than mix with JQuery, thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing jQuery and pure JS..

You should use `nextSibling()` & `removeChild(element)` on parent.
have a look here: [Remove element by id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387427/remove-element-by-id)

Answer (score 0):

The last `remove()` function  was on jquery function. so use jquery library link and call the `id` with jquery type.

```js
function colspan(){
     var x = document.getElementById("Cell2");
     x.setAttribute("colspan", 2);
     $('#Cell2').next().remove();
     }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
     <tr>
     <td id="Cell1">Cell 1</td>
     <td id="Cell2">Cell 2</td>
     <td id="Cell3">Cell 3</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td id="Cell4">Cell 4</td>
     <td id="Cell5">Cell 5</td>
     <td id="Cell6">Cell 6</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td id="Cell7">Cell 7</td>
     <td id="Cell8">Cell 8</td>
     <td id="Cell9">Cell 9</td>
     </tr>
     </table>
     
     <input type="button" onclick="colspan();" value="Change"/>
```