# how to remove placeholder in divi contact form by using javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress, divi

I want to know how we can remove placeholders of contact form in divi theme by the the help of JavaScript. So that when someone open this contact form the placeholder does not show to user.

Comment: are you looking for something like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/18120786/6689101

Comment: You can also edit the module, which is in my eyes better. But when you update Divi, you need to replace the file again after the update with the old one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If placeholder inside in input tag, you just can only delete then.

Example, i have this tag:

```
<input type='text' id='some' name='some' placeholder='some text goes here' />
```

And you want remove the **placeholder** tag, you could just remove it deleting it, but if you want remove it after some action, you could easy use JQuery .removeProp() (the [reference you could find here](https://api.jquery.com/removeProp/)), that depends the theme you're using in wordpress instalation.

Can be used css to remove it.

Example:

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit browsers */
    color:    #fff;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
   color:    #fff;
   opacity:  1;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
   color:    #fff;
   opacity:  1;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
   color:    #fff;
}
```

You could share the website link and informe the section you want remove that placeholder(s)