# How can I remove a footer element using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have HTML:

```
<footer class="footer">
    <div class="container-fluid wrapper">
    ...
    </div>
</footer>
```

How do I remove the whole footer markup using javascript (no jQuery available)?

I've tried:

```
var elem = document.getElementsByName("footer");
elem.remove();
```

...and a couple of other variations, but I can't get it to delete.

Any ideas?

Thanks, Mark

Comment: Why do you want to remove it? Would hiding it with a css modifier not be acceptable? Also you need to identify _which_ element in the returned collection you want to actually remove

Comment: Use removeChild via the parent, E.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387427/remove-element-by-id

Comment: Open your developer console, and you'll see the error. You can't call `.remove()` on a collection of elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do like this

```
function removeTagByTagName(tagName) {
  var ele = document.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
  return ele[0].parentNode.removeChild(ele[0]);
}
```

```js
function removeTag(tag) {
  var ele = document.getElementsByTagName(tag);
  return ele[0].parentNode.removeChild(ele[0]);
}

var btn = document.getElementById("delet");
btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
  removeTagByTagName("footer");
});
```

```html
<body>
<button id="delet">Delete Footer!</button>

  <footer class="footer" name="footer">
    <div class="container-fluid wrapper">
      blab bal babla
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

you cannot use .remove with all browsers, since the [support](http://caniuse.com/#search=remove) is not that good yet. I would recommend polyfilling the remove, so that you can use this. Use the following polyfill (taken from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove)):

```
// from:https://github.com/jserz/js_piece/blob/master/DOM/ChildNode/remove()/remove().md
(function (arr) {
  arr.forEach(function (item) {
    if (item.hasOwnProperty('remove')) {
      return;
    }
    Object.defineProperty(item, 'remove', {
      configurable: true,
      enumerable: true,
      writable: true,
      value: function remove() {
        this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
      }
    });
  });
})([Element.prototype, CharacterData.prototype, DocumentType.prototype]);
```

Now you can use .remove() with ease.

You can also use .removeChild() if you know the parent of the node you want to delete. Something like this:

```
var parent = document.getElementById("div1");
var child = document.getElementById("p1");
parent.removeChild(child);
```

So since your  is inside the , you can treat the body as the parent and remove its child () using similar code as above snippet.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to grab that specific footer element.  What you have with `var elem = document.getElementsByName("footer");` grabs a collection of all elements named "footer" but if you want to do it that way, you need to add the `name="footer"` attribute to your `footer` element.  The way your HTML is set up right now, you could change that line to:

```
var elem = document.getElementsByTagName("footer");
```

If you only have one `footer` element, then you can target that one like this:

```
var elem = document.getElementsByTagName("footer")[0];
```

Otherwise, you could assign that element an ID, or figure out which `footer` item in the collection it was (i.e. `document.getElementsByTagName("footer")[3]`).

Once you have that specific element, you can remove it like this:

```
elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
```

Comment: "grabs a collection of all footer elements" — It doesn't. It gets all elements with the attribute `name="footer"`.

Comment: @Quentin you're right, thanks for pointing that out.  I've corrected my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `removeChild` function and `querySelector` can be used to fulfil your needs.

```js
function remove(){
  var el=document.querySelector('footer.footer');
  el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
}
remove();
```

```html
<footer class="footer">
    <div class="container-fluid wrapper">
    ...
    </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Why are you asking when you haven't you commented on the answer that you down voted?

Comment: I would like to know why they downvoted and in which way I can improve. @squint