# chrome extension content script cant get element by class

Tags: javascript, class, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

Look at screenshot:

[image]

1. Iframe is minimized so you cant see any of its childs
2. Target div displayed as child of iframe even we know fact 1.

Extension's content script

```
console.log( targetDiv )   // output: undefined
```

Google Chrome console

```
console.log( targetDiv )   // output: targetDiv
```

How is that possible? 
The other 'normal' elements are printed out in both cases.
Can you explain me this magic half-child element?

**UPDATE:** **this div created dynamicly setInterval fixes problem!**

Comment: Your content script runs only in main page whereas console "context" selector is set to the iframe. You need to manually access the iframe's contentDocument if it's same-origin or you need `"all_frames": true` in manifest.json for the content script.

Comment: I already set all_frames true. Also as i say in post "The other elements are printed out in both cases." Content scirpt printed out undefined in iframe too. Also this div used as redirect for ad's. Thats why i want detect it and remove

Comment: Well, I have to guess since you didn't provide a URL to reproduce the behavior so my other guess would be the element is added dynamically and you need to access it later using MutationObserver or setInterval/setTimeout.

Comment: thanks you ! setInterval works... huh that stupid because i already tried use setTimeout with 2 secs delay and its not worked.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure that your script is loaded after that element is in DOM. Try to debug it, set up the breakpoint on your `console.log(targetDiv)` and investigate DOM manually. This element rendering may be delayed by some inner script for example. In that case you may implement a kind of polling process to detect this element in time:

```
const timer = setInterval(() => {
  const myElement = document.getElementById('my-element');
  if(myElement) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    processMyElement(myElement);
  }
}, 150);
```

instead of just

```
const myElement = document.getElementById('my-element');
processMyElement(myElement);
```

Comment: Now cant remove these divs, manually i can and they disappear for next reload, but from code i cant. Any ideas?)

Comment: @Lopol2010 What do you mean? `myElement.style.display = 'none'` should work after the element is rendered, also you would be able to completely remove it from DOM by for example [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19298575/3211932).

Comment: Thanks for help. Again my fault... Im tried remove element in Mutation Observer callback but i can only print it out from there. So i just place setInterval 100ms and element completely removed.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution to this can be to run the script after the page is fully loaded. Something like:

```
window.onload = function() {
   // run script
};
```

should work fine.

However, note that the script will run after all images and css are completely loaded and parsed.