# remove td classes from a Survey using javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm very new to javaScript and I'm trying to remove two td's but I can't manage to find a way of doing it.

These are the td's that I need to be removed in order to remove the spacing between the FIRST NAME and the LAST NAME. I also have to mention that I'm not allowed to edit the HTML directly.

```
<td class="error_label">
          <span id="ctl03" style="visibility:hidden;">Required Field</span>
        </td>

<td colspan="2" class="pd_question">
        <span id="lbl3"></span>
      </td>
```

Here is the whole code http://jsfiddle.net/w8z4nxa7/4/

Comment: Please add the relevant JavaScript to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, you have to select the element and then remove it using `.remove()` or `removeChild(...)`on its parent.

Timing is important, so that you don't try to select the elements before they are rendered on the page. For this, you put the `<script>` tag after the elements you want to work with or you add an `onload` or even better an `addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded")`:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
   document.querySelector('.error_label').remove()
   // and so on
});
```

Answer (score 1):

### Intro

You could try to remove them, by using a getElementByClassName.

So you need two things:

`document.getElementsByClassName` to get the actual element.

Once you get the element you need to remove it. `elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem)`.

### Quick rough example

```
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('error_label')[0];
elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
```

See: [Remove element by id](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3387427/1688441)