# How to remove a div in javascript with no jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to remove a div when you login (I know it's not secure!). I need it in javascript! I tried everything but it doesn't want to remove. the code is here ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------> I KNOW IT'S NOT SECURE! For some reason the script doesn't work! tried everything I know in javascript.

```js
var box = document.getElementById("loginbox");
function pasuser(form) {
if (form.email.value=="GG@gmail.com") {
console.log(form.email.value)
if (form.password.value=="123") {
  //window.location.assign('/index2.html');
  var next = document.createElement("IFRAME");
  next.src='https://codepen.io';
  next.classList.add("codepen");
  document.body.appendChild(next);
  //box.classList.remove("box");
  //box.style.display = "none";
  box.parentNode.removeChild(box);
  //box.outerHTML = "";
} else {
alert("Invalid Password");
}

} else {  alert("Invalid UserID");
}
}
```

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background: url(https://i.ytimg.com/vi/WLs_DST6dTA/maxresdefault.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}
.box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  width: 400px;
  padding: 40px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 25px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.box h2 {
  margin: 0 0 30px;
  padding: 0;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
}
.box h2:hover{
  letter-spacing: 5px;
}
.box .inputBox {
  position: relative;
}
.box .inputBox input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
}
.box .inputBox label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: .5s;
}
.box .inputBox input:focus ~ label,
.box .inputBox input:valid ~ label {
  top: -24px;
  left: 0;
  color: #03a9f4;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.box .inputBox input:focus,
.box .inputBox input:valid  {
  top: -26px;
  left: 0;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.box .inputBox input:active + .placeholder {
  color: #fff;
}
.box .inputBox input:focus{
  border: solid 1px #03a9f4;
  border-radius: 5px;
  
}
.box input[type="button"] {
  background: transparent;
  border: 2px solid #03a9f4;
  outline: none;
  color: #03a9f4;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-out;
  transition: all .2s ease;
}
.box input[type="button"]:hover{
  border: 2px solid #03a9f4;
  background: #03a9f4;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
.codepen {
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  height: 620px;
}
.hide {
display:none !important;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
  <script src="/server.js"></script>
  <script src="/next.js"></script>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="loginbox" class="box">
    <h2>Login</h2>
    <form autocomplete="on" method="post" action="./index2.html">
      <div class="inputBox">
        <input id="email" type="email" name="email" required="" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="email" dir="ltr" autocapitalize="none">
        <label>Username</label>
      </div>
      <div class="inputBox">
        <input id="password" type="password" name="pass" required="" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="new-password" dir="ltr" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off">
        <label>Password</label>
      </div>
      <input id="submitBtn" type="button" value="Submit" onclick="pasuser(form)">
    </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove element by id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387427/remove-element-by-id)

Comment: what div   do you like delete ?

Comment: The div with the id="loginbox"

Comment: document.querySelector("#loginbox").remove()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
document.getElementById("loginbox").remove();
```

to fit in your code:

```
box.remove();
```

Comment: I just tried copying and pasting your code into an html file and it works perfectly. Could you just check the message you get on the console and paste it here?

Comment: Thanks forgot to refresh page!