# How to remove a div from unique id?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I remove a div from a unique id? I've tried many ways but always fail.

```js
function uniqId() {
  return Math.round(new Date().getTime() + (Math.random() * 100));
}


function sklik() {
  var dov1 = `<div class="dwnctrl d-flex mt-3" id="` + uniqId() + `">
    <input class="form-control mr-2" name="" id="" placeholder="Quality" style="width: 100px;">
    <input class="form-control mr-2" name="" id="" placeholder="Link">
    <input class="form-control mr-2" name="" id="" placeholder="Server Name" style="width: 150px;">
    <button type="button" class="btn toddd" id="post-grab" onclick="rmv()">Remove</button>
  </div>`;
  $(".frmDowns").after(dov1);
}
```

Comment: Since you're using jQuery, have you tried `bind()` or `on()` on the particular element in question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove element by id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387427/remove-element-by-id)

Comment: Also note that the entire point of template literals is that you don't need to concatenate. Change ```id="` + uniqId() + `"``` to `id="${uniqId}"`

Answer (score 2):

You need to remember the unique id and pass it to the remove function

```
function uniqId() {
   return Math.round(new Date().getTime() + (Math.random() * 100));
}

function sklik(){
    var uniqId = uniqId();
    var dov1 = `<div class="dwnctrl d-flex mt-3" id="${uniqId}">
        <input class="form-control mr-2" name="" id="" placeholder="Quality" style="width: 100px;">
        <input class="form-control mr-2" name="" id="" placeholder="Link">
        <input class="form-control mr-2" name="" id="" placeholder="Server Name" style="width: 150px;">
        <button type="button" class="btn toddd" id="post-grab" onclick="$('#${uniqId}').remove()">Remove</button>
        </div>`;
        $(".frmDowns").after(dov1);
}
```

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I just wrote the key point,in fact I think the OP's code need to improve,he has mixed double quote and single quote,am I right?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Sorry,but I think when I pass the id of the div,it can remove the div,what's wrong with my answer,can you help me,thanks in advance!

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222723/discussion-between-lucumt-and-rory-mccrossan).

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan will `onclick="$('#"+uniqId+"').remove()` not able to remove the div?I am a bit confused

Comment: After the edit yes - although your quotes are mismatched. I've edited to fix that for you and removed my comments as they now aren't needed

Answer (score 1):

First your usage of string template literals is totally wrong. It needs to be `${theVariable}`

```js
let _currentId = 0

function addRow() {

  const uniqueId = "row" + _currentId++;

  var dov1 = `<div class="dwnctrl d-flex mt-3" id='${uniqueId}'>
            <input class="form-control mr-2" name="" id="" placeholder="Quality" style="width: 100px;">
            <input class="form-control mr-2" name="" id="" placeholder="Link">
            <input class="form-control mr-2" name="" id="" placeholder="Server Name" style="width: 150px;">
            <button type="button" class="btn toddd" id="post-grab" onclick="$('#${uniqueId}').remove()">Remove</button>
            </div>                        
            `;
  $(".frmDowns").append(dov1);
}

addRow();
addRow();
addRow();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="frmDowns"></div>
```

Why even use the id? You can use event delegation and select the ancestor and remove the row.

```js
let _currentId = 0

function addRow() {

  const uniqueId = "row" + _currentId++;

  var dov1 = `<div class="dwnctrl d-flex mt-3" id='${uniqueId}'>
            <input class="form-control mr-2" name="" id="" placeholder="Quality" style="width: 100px;">
            <input class="form-control mr-2" name="" id="" placeholder="Link">
            <input class="form-control mr-2" name="" id="" placeholder="Server Name" style="width: 150px;">
            <button type="button" class="btn toddd remove">Remove</button>
            </div>                        
            `;
  $(".frmDowns").append(dov1);
}

addRow();
addRow();
addRow();

$(".frmDowns").on("click", "button.remove", function() {
  $(this).closest('.dwnctrl').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="frmDowns"></div>
```