# Remove Button on click

Tags: javascript, html

I want to remove the button itself onclick. Can someone help me.

HTML:

```
<div id="hideButton">
    <a onclick="removeButton()" class="button1">PRESS</a>
</div>
```

Java Script:

```
function removeButton() {
    var element = document.getElementsById("hidebutton");
    element.classList.remove("button1");
  }
```

Every help is much appreciated :)

Comment: `document.getElementById` not `document.getElementsById` (no s)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove element by id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387427/remove-element-by-id)

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript's **remove()** function.

```js
function removeButton() {
  var button = document.getElementById("hideButton");
  button.remove();
}
```

```html
<div id="hideButton">
    <a onclick="removeButton()" class="button1">PRESS</a>
</div>
```

Comment: how this will remove button. It will remove complete div. The user wants to remove button on self click.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div id="hideButton">
    <a onclick="removeButton(this)" class="button1">PRESS</a>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
function removeButton(buttonCntrl) {            
    buttonCntrl.remove();
}
```

Comment: note that using `onclick="removeButton(this)"` is bad, using eventListeners are way better

Answer (score 0):

If you wished to apply this same logic to multiple `button1`  elements you can use a single external event listener bound to every instance of that class using `querySelectorAll` to find these elements.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('a.button1').forEach(a=>a.addEventListener('click',function(e){
  this.parentNode.removeChild(this)
}));
```

```css
.button1{
  border:1px solid black;
  width:120px;
  padding:0.25rem;
}

div{
  margin:1rem;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <a href='#' class="button1">PRESS #1</a>
</div>

<div>
    <a href='#' class="button1">PRESS #2</a>
</div>

<div>
    <a href='#' class="button1">PRESS #3</a>
</div>

<div>
    <a href='#' class="button1">PRESS #4</a>
</div>

<div>
    <a href='#' class="button1">PRESS #5</a>
</div>
```