# How i can delete span text made in js?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I delete or hide the text while somebody in my form input in the second time give correct data? I mean when somebody on first time give incorrect the text will display "First Name cannot be empty!" and then give correct data and the text is there but invisible.

```
        errorFunc(fname, 'First Name cannot be empty!')
    } else {
        successFunc(fname)
    }

    if (lastName === '') {
        errorFunc(lname, 'Last name cannot be empty!')
    } else {
        successFunc(lname)
    }

function errorFunc(req, message) {
    const formControl = req.parentElement;
    const span = formControl.querySelector('span');
    span.innerText = message;
    req.classList.add('error');
    span.classList.add('error-text');
    req.classList.remove('success');
}

function successFunc(req) {
    const formControl = req.parentElement;
    const span = formControl.querySelector('span');
    req.classList.add('success');
    req.classList.remove('error')
    span.classList.remove('error-text')
}
```

Comment: Just do this at the beginning of your validation script: `formControl.querySelector('span').innerText=""` - clear it out each time you validate as your validation script will put text in it afterwards if neccesary

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove element by id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387427/remove-element-by-id)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 options:

- You can remove the span with  .remove() function.

  ```
  span.remove()
  ```
- Also you can maintain the span element but remove text.

  ```
  span.innerText = ""
  ```